# Englische Verben im Deutschen

Tags: word-usage, verb, meaning-in-context

Im Alltagsdeutsch höre ich viele englische Verben wie beispielsweise *surfen*, *switchen*, *checken*, *managen* und so weiter und so fort.

Kann man einfach ein englisches Verb so im Alltag verwenden, wenn einem ein deutsches Verb nicht einfällt, oder hört sich so eine Verwendung manchmal komisch an?

Comment: Dass es gemacht wird: Ist eine Tatsache (Wir würden übrigens viele, wenn nicht alle deiner Beispiele als angenommene Bestandteile des Deutschen betrachten, nicht als englische Verben). Ob es akzeptabel ist: Hängt wohl eher von der persönlichen Auffassung ab, und wird mit Sicherheit akzeptabler, wenn es ein ähnliches Verb im Deutschen *nicht* gibt: *wellenbrettfahren* ist nicht sehr gebräuchlich. Ob es sinnvoll ist: Wenn der Gesprächspartner kein Englisch kann, sicher nicht. Ob es sich komisch anhört: Je mehr der obigen Bedingungen nicht erfüllt sind, umso komischer.

Comment: @userunknown Manchmal frage ich mich, ob du weißt, dass eine Frage aus dem Close-Vote-Review herausfällt, wenn du *edit* auswählst.

Comment: @Jan: Manchmal frage ich mich, wieso man eine Frage nicht erst auf Vodermann bringt, bevor man sie dann trotzdem zum Schließen vorschlägt.

Comment: Ob man einfach so ein englisches Wort verwenden can ist eine Frage, die man völlig meinungsfrei mit Nein answering muss. Und komisch wird es sehr oft sounden - auch das ist keine Frage der Meinung.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nein, man kann nicht einfach ein englisches Verb eindeutschen, wenn einem das deutsche nicht einfällt.

Oft kennt nämlich der Hörer oder Leser kein Englisch. Oft will der Sprecher/Schreiber mit einem Anglizismus etwas ausdrücken, etwa Zugehörigkeit zu einer internationalen Insidergroup, in der alle so sprechen, oder doch so oft englisch sprechen, dass ihnen die englische Vokabel näher liegt als die deutsche.

> Ich runne jetzt noch 30 Minuten für meine schlanke Linie.

To run, obwohl eines der bekanntesten, englischen Wörter habe ich noch nie gehört.

Comment: Ja, du hast recht aber in den großen Wörterbüchern z.B Duden oder Langenscheidt, ich habe die Wörter wie determinieren (bestimmen) oder insistieren (bestehen auf) gesehen, auch wenn es perfekte deutsche Äquivalente gibt. Ist diese Verwendung von englischen Verben meistens unter Teenagers, die cool aussehen wollen?

Comment: @AdInfinitum *determinieren* und *insistieren* sind keine aus dem **Englischen** übernommenen Wörter - Sowohl die englische als auch die deutsche Sprache haben diese Wörter aus dem Lateinischen übernommen.

Comment: @tofro danke schön für die Antwort. Ich habe die deutsche Sprache nach dem Englischen gelernt. Deswegen denke ich automatisch, dass solche Wörter aus dem Englischen gekommen sind.

Comment: @AdInfinitum: Zu verschiedenen Epochen und in verschiedenen sozialen Grupppen wurden Wörter aus unterschiedlichen Sprachen übernommen. Etwa Kircheneinfluss: Latein, höfische Gesellschaft: Französisch, Rock-und-Popkultur: Englisch, Wirtschaft, Marketing: Englisch. Da Englisch heute die dominierende Wissenschaftssprache ist übernimmt man heute in den meisten Wissenschaften englische Begrife. In einer Jugendclique kann aber jeder einzelne versuchen neue Begriffe zu etablieren (Das sounded strange!) und wird in der Clique verstanden, evtl. verbreitet sich der Sprachgebrauch.