# Wie soll man eingedeutschte Verben richtig konjugieren?

Tags: verb-usage, prefix, conjugation, loanword

Vor circa einem Jahr habe ich [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30533/englische-verben-im-deutschen) gestellt, aber heute fällt mir auf, dass alle eingedeutschte Verben anders in Plusquamperfekt konjugiert werden.

Ein paar Beispiele aus dem Internet:

---

**Debuggen**

> Ich habe **gedebuggt** um zu schauen, aus welcher Stelle die Exception kommt
>
> Ich habe **debuggt** und die Nachricht kam an folgendem Abschnitt nicht zur Console

---

**Updaten**

> Er hat **upgedatet** auf version 6.x und es werden keine mail mehr geholt.
>
> Heute hab ich mich auf Minecraft eingeloggt und er hat **geupdatet**

---

Sowieso finde ich es peinlich, ein englisches Wort zu benutzen, wenn ich Deutsch spreche, aber zumindest will ich es richtig konjugieren, wenn ich eines davon benutzen muss.

Ich weiß, dass es keine richtige Antwort zu dieser Frage gibt, weil die Wörter überhaupt nicht Deutsch sind, aber welche von den obigen Konjugationen klingen natürlicher?

Comment: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/2358/1224 — And I think there was another more generic question. Can't find it, though.

Comment: Darüberhinaus *gibt* es eine richtige Antwort auf die Frage. Das mögen ursprünglich keine dt. Wörter gewesen sein, aber einige sind inzw. in den dt. Wortschatz übergegangen. Selbst wenn du jetzt ein weiteres Wort aus dem Englisch importierst, so kannst du auf Basis bereits übernommener Wörter die Konjugation ableiten. (Die übrigens mit der Konjugation urdeutscher Wörter übereinstimmt.)

Comment: [Zur Rechtschreibung](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/4435/2594) solcher Wörter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich habe mal mit Arbeitskollegen über den korrekten Plural von "Status" diskutiert und nachdem wir mit "Statüsse" nicht zufrieden waren, haben wir uns auf "Zustände" geeinigt. Manchmal gibt es eine viel einfachere Lösung als man denkt.

Sollte man trotzdem debuggen statt nach dem Fehler suchen oder updaten statt aktualisieren, musst du trotzdem nach der deutschen Grammatik konjugieren. Beim Partizip ist es vielleicht nicht so offensichtlich, aber lass dir den Präsens über die Zunge gehen und probier mal was richtig und was falsch klingt:

- "ich debugge" oder "ich debug"?
- "du debugst" oder "du debug"?
- "er debugt" oder "er debugs"?
- "wir debuggen" oder "wir debug"?
- "ihr debugt" oder "ihr debug"?
- "sie debuggen" oder "sie debug"?

Heißt es nun aber upgedatet oder geupdatet? Die Hauptregel sagt, dass betonte Präfixe getrennt werden und "up" in "updaten" ist nun mal betont. Es müsste also heißen: "er hat upgedatet".

Tofro scheint zu meinen, dass es "er hat geupdatet" heißen muss, weil ein trennbares Verb eine *deutsche* Vorsilbe brauche. Ich bin mir nicht sicher woher er das hat. Deutsch ist zwar nicht meine Muttersprache, aber ich habe nun mal in der Schule gelernt, dass ein Verb getrennt wird, wenn das Präfix betont wird. Jetzt habe ich in mehreren Grammatiken nachgeguckt und sie stimmen mir alle zu. Gerade deswegen werden einige Verben, die abhängig von der Bedeutung unterschiedlich betont werden, auch mal getrennt, mal nicht, z.B: Ich stelle meine Uhr um (getrennt, weil Betonung auf "um": ˈʊmʃtɛlən), aber die Polizei umstellt den Verbrecher (nicht getrennt, weil keine Betonung auf "um": ʊmˈʃtɛlən).

Falls Duden als Referenz noch durchgeht, führt Duden auch "upgedatet" als Partizip auf: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/updaten

**Edit:** Es hat sich ergeben, dass tofro sich auf die Rechtschreibregeln des Rechtschreibrats, § 34 beruft. Dort gäbe es angeblich Listen, die nicht "up" als trennbares Präfix enthalten, die Regeln sehen keine fremdsprachliche Zusammensetzung vor und deswegen sei "updaten" auch nicht trennbar. Ein Kommentar reicht nicht aus, um seine Behauptung zu widersprechen, aber ich kann gerne hier ausführlich darauf eingehen. In der aktuellen Fassung der Rechtschreibregeln steht eben nichts drin, woraus seine Behauptungen abgeleitet werden können.

tofro behauptet, dass "updaten" nicht trennbar ist, weil die Listen in § 34 der genannten Rechtschreibung nicht "up" als trennbares Präfix enthalten. § 34 beschreibt die verschiedene Kategorien trennbarer Präfixe und nennt zu jede Kategorie einige Beispiele. Ich vermute, dass diese Beispiele die Listen sind, worauf sich tofro beruft. Hier geht es aber nur darum einige Beispiele zu nennen (alle Listen werden mit "zum Beispiel:" eingeleitet) und sie erheben kein Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit. Die Abwesenheit von "up" in den Beispielen ist also kein Argument dafür, dass "updaten" nicht trennbar sein kann. Das deutsche Präfix "fern" kommt in den Listen auch nicht vor, trotzdem sagt man nicht "Ich bin aus der Schule gefernblieben, weil ich zu Hause gefernsehen habe."

Ferner schreibt tofro, dass fremdsprachliche Zusammensetzungen nicht vorgesehen sind, was auch nicht stimmt. Die Herkunftssprache der Zusammensetzungen wird in § 34 nirgendwo erwähnt und ich weiß nicht warum die eine Rolle spielen sollte. § 34 legt trennbare Präfixe nach Kriterien fest, die unabhängig von der Sprache sind.

Comment: Keine Ahnung, was "Status" in dieser Antwort verloren hat, aber der Plural ist "Status" mit langem u, "Statuuuuuuuus".

Comment: Und wenn man "up" wie einen trennbaren Präfix behandeln würde, würde man ja auch "Date das mal up!" sagen. Macht aber keiner, man sagt "Update das mal!". Es ist halt nicht so einfach, importierte Verben dem deutschen Schema unterzuordnen.

Comment: Die Form »upgedatet« deutet aber auf ein trennbares Verb hin. Vergleiche mit *einkaufen*: »Ich habe *eingekauft*, ich werde *einkaufen*, ich **kaufe ein**«. Dasselbe mit *updaten*: »Ich habe *upgedatet*, ich werde *updaten*, ich **date up**«.

Comment: Trennbare Verben sind Verben mit bestimmten **deutschen** Vorsilben, die u.U. abgetrennt werden (z.B. "ab-", "auf-", "durch-", u.s.w). Für ein *eingedeutschtes* Verb dürfte sich eine solche Vorsilbe ausschließen.

Comment: @tofro Es fordert kein Regelwerk, dass ein trennbares Verb ein *deutsches* Präfix haben muss. Duden listet auch wie erwartet updaten als trennbares Verb (hat upgedatet): http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/updaten

Comment: @jarnbjo Mit Verlaub, *diesen* Duden-Eintrag halte ich für ausgesprochenen Unsinn... Die meisten Grammatiken, die ich kenne, listen die trennbaren Präfixe auf: "up-" habe ich in noch keiner Liste gefunden.

Comment: @tofro: Woher hast du es, dass trennbare Verben nur bestimmte deutschen Präfixe haben dürfen und welche Präfixe sollten das sein?

Comment: In dieser Konsequenz müsste man, wäre "updaten" ein regulär trennbares Verb, auch "ich date up" sagen - Spätestens hier tritt der Unsinn zu Tage.

Comment: @tofro dirkt hat schon gestern geschrieben, dass "ich date up" falsch klingt (was ich allerdings nicht zustimme) und es beantwortet nicht meine Frage zu deinem Einwand, dass du es heute wiederholst. Ich probiere nochmal: Wenn es deiner Meinung nach eine festgelegte Liste von trennbaren Präfixen gibt, die nicht erweitert werden darf, welche Präfixe sollten das sein? Du behauptest es gäbe sowas, kannst aber nicht erklären woher du das hast und welche Liste das sein sollte. *Das* ist doch, von meiner Seite auch mit Verlaub, Unsinn.

Comment: @jarnbjo Nimm die Rechtschreibregeln des Rechtschreibrats und lies §34 - Da hast du deine Liste. *up-* kommt darin nicht vor. Dort steht auch, wie trennbare und nicht trennbare Verben zusammengesetzt werden - Eine aus einem fremdsprachlichen Verb übernommene Zusammensetzung ist dort nicht vorgesehen.

Comment: @tofro Grammatiken, die Präfixe auflisten, beinhalten aber auch nicht "hoch" (Bsp. "hochladen"). "Hoch" (und auch "up") sind im Grunde Adverbien, die mit dem Verb verschmolzen sind. Die Grammatiken listen normalerweise Präpositionen auf, oder gar Präfixe die alleine gar nicht stehen können (zB erz, ur). Insofern erwarte ich auch keine Liste, die "up" beinhaltet; und dennoch ist es ein sinnvolles (weil gängiges) Beispiel, wenn man auf eingedeutsche Wörter eingeht.

Comment: @Em1 Kann etwa "up-" als Präfix im Deutschen alleine stehen??? Und "up" ist kein mir bekanntes deutsches Adverb.

Comment: @tofro Omg, warum hast du Aussagen hinzugedichtet, die ich nicht geschrieben habe? Ach egal. *augenroll*

Answer (score 2):

Importierte Verben sind grundsätzlich *schwache Verben*, die deswegen nach festen Regeln konjugiert werden.

Die Konjugation von schwachen Verben ist eindeutig definiert und folgt der festen Regel, dass es keine Stammlautveränderung gibt und die Konjugationen alle gleich gebildet werden (Stammform bilden und entsprechende Endung anhängen, für's Partizip ein "ge-" vorsetzen).

Trennbar kann ein solches Verb auch nicht sein, da ihm per Definition eine abtrennbare deutsche Vorsilbe fehlen muss.

Damit ist "upgedatet" schonmal falsch. Es muss "geupdatet" heißen.

Noch eine Bemerkung dazu, dass es Leute (und auch den Duden) gibt, die meinen, dass "updaten" ein trennbares Verb sei. Zuerst mal ist das ein fremdsprachliches Wort, das einem nur der deutschen Sprache Mächtigen vollkommen unbekannt sein muss. Woher dieser arme Mensch wissen soll, dass "up-" im Englischen ein Adverb ist, das auch alleine stehen kann und damit möglicherweise abtrennbar sein könnte, erschließt sich mir nicht. Genausogut könnte man argumentieren, das "per-" ein gängiges lateinisches Adverb wäre, das abtrennbar sei. Damit wäre zum Beispiel "permutieren" ein trennbares Verb, und es hieße "Ich mutierte die Ziffern per". Das Vermischen von fremdsprachlicher und deutscher Grammatik ist hier einfach nicht sinnvoll. Der Brite sagt ja auch nicht "I dated up."

Ich kann durchaus erkennen, das es eine gängige Unsitte ist, "ich habe upgedatet" zu sagen. Ich persönlich halte die Trennung dieses Verbs aber trotzdem für einen klaren Fall von sprachlicher [Hyperkorrektur](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperkorrektur) ("Ich weiss, dass "up" im Englischen was bedeutet und alleine stehen kann, betrachte es deshalb als abtrennbares Präfix").

Comment: Duden richtet sich nach den Leuten und nicht anders herum. Noch ist es nämlich so, dass sich Rechtschreibung und Grammatik nach den Leuten richtet und Regeln nur deskriptiv dem Sprachgebrauch folgen. Ausnahmen davon sind die großen Rechtschreibreformen, die man genau deswegen auch kritisch sehen kann, und solche Regeln, die zwingend im Staatsdienst (also auch Schule) befolgt werden müssen.

Comment: @Takkat Der Duden ist inzwischen einfach nur noch ein Buch. Da können sinnvolle und weniger sinnvolle Sachen drinstehen, und nicht alles muss unbedingt richtig sein. Speziell die Behauptung "updaten" sei ein trennbares Verb halte ich, wenn überhaupt durch die "Leute" begründbar, für einen kollektiven Irrtum.

Answer (score 2):

Ich habe einen [Artikel](http://informatik.karlheinz-hug.de/b+m-k+t/OBSD.htm) über dieses Thema gefunden. Das beantwortet meine eigene Frage nicht ganz aber es lohnt sich auf jeden Fall, den Artikel (zumindest den **Denglisch**-Teil) zu lesen.

Ein Abschnitt aus dem Artikel:

> Ein Beispiel für eine gelungene Assimilation (Einbürgerung) des
>   englischen "to test" sind die Wörter "testen, testete, getestet, der
>   Test, -s, testbar": Sie passen von der Aussprache, der Schreibweise
>   und der Grammatik zu den deutschen Regeln.
>
> Bei vielen englischen Wörtern klappt das aber nicht, z.B. scheitert
>   das Flektieren oft schon beim Partizip Perfekt. Nehmen wir als
>   Problemfall "to deploy": Nicht übersetzt lautet es etwa "deployen,
>   deployte, deployt", was in Aussprache und Schreibweise deutschen
>   Regeln widerspricht. Wollte man es anpassen, so müsste man "depleuen,
>   depleute, depleut" sprechen und schreiben. Das Substantiv "deployment"
>   würde zu "Depleuung", das Adjektiv "deployable" zu "depleubar". Sollen
>   wir uns das antun oder nach einem passenden deutschen Begriff suchen?

Comment: Und genau das wollte ich mit der Einleitung meiner Antwort sagen: Oft ist es einfacher Deutsch zu sprechen, statt zu versuchen Fremwörter der deutschen Grammatik anzupassen ;-)

Comment: @jarnbjo Natürlich ist was du sagst indiskutabel. Aber manche Leute sind sehr an das Fremdwort gewöhnt und sie verstehen mich nicht, wenn ich das deutsche Äquivalent benutze und darüberhinaus gibt es manchmal überhaupt kein deutsches Äquivalent (z.B to brainstorm, to layout), das ich benutzen kann.

Answer (score 0):

Particularly in the case of "update" I've experienced many times that native German speakers simply used the English version in Perfekt. "Das Tool wurde updated", so. I think the reason behind that the languages are too similar, and it enables for them to import also grammatical structures from it, not only the words. I think it may be also the reason, why - particularly younger Germans - are currently starting to use normal word ordering even in Nebensätzen or after "weil". Google for Bastian Sick, he has some funny texts about the phenomenon.

I don't think that it would be a good thing, because German is logical and beautiful, and English is not. Doing this is a clear loss.

Comment: You are right. Not only *update* but also other verbs as well. I have heard lots of time when they said debugged/deployed/managed. That was actually the reason for this question.